# Dynamic callback url laravel

Tags: laravel

I tried to make my callback url dynamic because I'm configuring socialite in a multi auth system. I tried to use the `socialiteproviders/manager` as below:

```
    $clientId = env($provider."_client_id");
    $clientSecret = env($provider."_client_secret");
    $redirectUrl = "the url i want";
    $config = new \SocialiteProviders\Manager\Config($clientId,$clientSecret,$redirectUrl);
    return Socialite::with($provider)->setConfig($config)->redirect();
```

but it says:

> Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider::setConfig()

when trying to login with facebook.

Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce and found a solution. The code you provided was outdated, and I found other instances of it here: https://laravel.io/forum/07-28-2016-dynamic-callback-url-laravel-socialite

By default, Socialite will get the provider config in `services.php` by passing the $providerName = `facebook`

So your code now becomes:

```
// The services.php config will return null, fix it by using: strtoupper()

$clientId = env(strtoupper($provider . "_client_id"));
$clientSecret = env(strtoupper($provider . "_client_secret"));
$redirectUrl = "/the-url-i-want";

// ->redirect() acts as a closure, without it, you'll get an error like:
// "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"

$user = Socialite::with($provider)->redirect();
return redirect()->to($redirectUrl)->with(['user', $user]);
```

More info on redirecting with session data:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data